# What is the point of do_handshake in

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, network-programming, tls1.2

I need to create a TLS client that performs TLS handshake. I use `context.wrap_socket` which takes an argument `do_handshake_on_connect` that takes either `True` or `False`. However, I have been doing handshakes without settings this variable to True (I do not pass it at all). And I get handshake results such as the selected TLS ciphersuite and version by the server.

Am I missing something? What is the point of `do_handshake_on_connect` if it is implicitly done when I do: `ssl_sock.connect`
I could not get the point and I am afraid I am missing something.

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the point of do_handshake_on_connect if it is implicitly done when I do: `ssl_sock.connect`

The point is clearly shown in [the official documantion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#socket-creation). To cite:

> The parameter do_handshake_on_connect specifies whether to do the SSL handshake automatically after doing a socket.connect(), or whether the application program will call it explicitly, by invoking the SSLSocket.do_handshake() method. **Calling SSLSocket.do_handshake() explicitly gives the program control over the blocking behavior of the socket I/O involved in the handshake**.